# For loop in Length computation code

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Here is a code I wrote that is supposed to give the length of list after some splitting and regrouping. But it is inefficient. Is there a way to rewrite in more professional and efficient way? I guess the procedural loop should be replaced with some functional command. Not sure how though, so as not to overload the memory.

```
NN=10^9;      
 ll = Range[12];
        k = 0; n = 7;
        AbsoluteTiming@(For[i = 1, i <= NN, i++,

            k += Length[
               Split[Sort[RandomSample[ll, n], Less], #1 - #2 == -1 &]];

            ];)
        k
```

Update:

Thanks a lot. I made a logical mistake in my code, it shouldn't randomize while iterating `n` for later calculation of the distribution with maximum number of subsets in the process of building up:

```
AbsoluteTiming@(s = 10^4; NN = 12;
  ll = Range[NN];

  t = Table[tt = RandomSample[ll]; 
    Table[Sort[Take[tt, j], Less], {j, NN}], {s}];


  t = Map[1 + Total[Unitize[Rest[#] - Most[#] - 1]] &, t, {2}];
  final = Map[Max, t];
  Mean[final] // N)
```

So basically it outputs the largest number of consecutively arranged subsets.

Is Patrick's fast answer applicable in this case too? How and why?

Comment: What is this code trying to calculate?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey this a question out of ignorance. Do you have an automated or other way to place these welcome messages (which are very very useful)...I am sorry to be ignorant of this

Comment: @ubpdqn  If I recall correctly, there is a standard welcome message, but I use the one above, because it covers more and (I believe) in a better order.  When I happen to see a new member question, I copy this message from my computer and paste it into a comment.  I know of no automated way to do this.  Too bad.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you for the information...will try to be as responsible myself in future:)

Comment: a bit of an aside, but note `Less` is `Sort`s default, however actually giving it that argument slows it down a fair bit.  Also `Count[Differences@Sort[ ..], 1]` beats `Length@Split` by a good bit.

Comment: @george, `OrderedQ[]` is the default, not `Less[]`. Consider the result of `Sort[{Pi/6, E, Glaisher}]`, and then try adding `Less`.

Comment: Fair enough, but note actually specifying `OrderedQ[{##}] &` is even slower than `Less`. The point being that where possible you should avoid the extra argument.

Comment: Have any answers satisfied your question? If not, please take the time to comment on how they can.

Comment: I'm going to ask, once more, for clarification re: what it is you're  calculating. A proper description, not code one must decode, that itself turns out was wrong. In addition specify over what domain this is to be done: is it a one-shot over lists of 12, or does the length vary (and get larger, where a subset based answer will fail). Barring that, it's unclear what you are asking, and question will get closed.

Comment: In answer to your second query, perhaps my graph was confusing: *Patrick*'s answer is the *slowest* (I did not benchmark *ubpdqn*'s, it was not written for speed, but to show an alternative, one that *may in fact be the best way to do this*, if readers knew what the changing "this" was). In addition, you seem to have taken ideas from the answer(s), munged the code to do the same thing, but with less efficiency. Puzzling, to say the least when " Is there a way to rewrite in ... efficient way?" is part of the nut graph in the OP...

Comment: Lastly, by "distribution", be aware the distribution of lengths of splits for some random permutation of the list is a *very* different thing than the "distribution" of the maximum split length of some permutation over a sliding window (what you're doing now). That combined with your statement of "...I shouldn't randomize with iterating..." hints you wanted the former (i.e., you wanted to get the average length, and distribution of lengths for a random permutation). You're not getting that distribution the way you're gathering data, nor the actual average. Is that what you actually intended?

Comment: Thanks again, guys, for all your suggestions. Just by going through them improved my shoddy skills. I am solving the problem when one randomly picks links of numbered chain of N links, then connects each link to the ones that have number right next to it (say if you pulled out linked 2 and you had already a subchain {3,4,5} you would attach it to that and get {2.3.4.5}, if it doesn't match any

Comment: subchain, then it stays standalone). So by pulling links the subchains will grow and merge and one will get a chain of N links with mingles numbers. The question is to find the distribution of maximum number of subchains in this process with as much precision as possible. I just did a stupid thing by trying to write a code at face. Now I realize I should have came up with some analytical simplifications, or just direct solution. If this is a textbook problem, it should have been not just purely coding exercise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The immediate improvement you wanted was the following, but of course it uses large amounts of memory:

```
NN = 10^9;
Total@Table[Length[Split[
 Sort[RandomSample[Range[12], 7], Less], #1 - #2 == -1 &]], {i, 1,
 NN}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

That is, using `Table` and `Total` (but it consumes all the memory of my 16GB RAM machine).

However, there are only 792 different subsets of length 7 drawn from `Range[1,12]`. Therefore, I can give you the exact mean of the estimator you have constructed:

```
NN = 10^9;
subs = Length@Split[#, #1 - #2 == -1 &] & /@ Subsets[Range[12], {7}];
Mean[subs]*NN
```

This takes basically no memory. Sorry that this doesn't really answer the general question, but it answers the specific.

Comment: Probably `Subsets[Range[12], {7}]` intead of `Subsets[Range[12], 7]`

Comment: I assumed simulation the goal, if not, your latter is the way to do it barring OP detailing the goal and it lends itself to direct probabilistic calculations. +1

Comment: Thanks, belisarius - fixed the typo.

Comment: FWIW in this case the `Table` result, although it looks more satisfactory is only very marginally faster than the `For` loop (avoiding memory issues tested with smaller `NN` like 10^6 ).  Ultimately it seems if you want to brute force crunch it out the procedural loop is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a logical mistake in my code, it shouldn't randomize while iterating `i`:

`AbsoluteTiming@(s = 10^4; NN = 12;
  ll = Range[NN];
  
  t = Table[tt = RandomSample[ll]; 
    Table[Sort[Take[tt, j], Less], {j, NN}], {s}];
  
  
  t = Map[1 + Total[Unitize[Rest[#] - Most[#] - 1]] &, t, {2}];
  final = Map[Max, t];
  Mean[final] // N)`

So basically it outputs the largest number of consecutively arranged subsets.

Is Patrick's fast answer applicable in this case too?

Answer (score 4):

Exploiting @ciao efficient way of counting the length of splits ( I have upvoted his answer) allows exact calculation of expectation of split length for this setup. The 792 (`Binomial[12,7]`) cases make it tractable.

```
tally = Tally[
   6 - ((Tr@Unitize@Subtract[Differences@#, 1]) & /@ 
      Subsets[Range[12], {7}])];
tot = Total@tally[[All, 2]];
prob = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{#2/tot, u == #1} & @@@ tally], {u, 1, 6, 1}]
Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] prob]
```

yielding 7/2 which the simulations approach.

Noting there can not be length of split >6 given 7 elements and if all 6 elements chosen split seventh chosen must be within 1 of an element. The 6 cases of 6 split:

```
{{{1, 2}, {4}, {6}, {8}, {10}, {12}}, {{1}, {3, 
   4}, {6}, {8}, {10}, {12}}, {{1}, {3}, {5, 
   6}, {8}, {10}, {12}}, {{1}, {3}, {5}, {7, 
   8}, {10}, {12}}, {{1}, {3}, {5}, {7}, {9, 
   10}, {12}}, {{1}, {3}, {5}, {7}, {9}, {11, 12}}}
```

Comment: Use of probability functions makes for smiles, +1. Of course, if the OP is after more than just this particular case, all of our solutions go bonkers (range 100 taken 30 at a time, anyone?). I'm on to something for those, assuming OP comments/updates post with more info.

Answer (score 4):

Since you changed the question completely and rendered every answer posted and the effort involved moot, here's a method to compute the *exact* PMF and Mean for your new formulation with nearly nil memory requirements.

Since you've not responded to requests by me and others to clarify precisely what it is you're after, I don't plan on spending any time deriving the closed form for the exact distribution and mean as I did for the first round of your question - that was, while on the order of minutes, non-trivial, and the structure of the latest machinations seems considerably more fiendish, probably on the order of hours to figure it out or show it does not/might not exist. (And, lacking clarification, I wonder if it's really what you think it is/you're after).

In any case:

```
ClearAll[cnts, ge, base, perm, k, j, size]
size = 12;
ge = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup@size, {k}];
bins = Ceiling[size/2];
(cnts[#] = 0) & /@ Range@bins;
base = Range@size;
Do[
  perm = Permute[base, First@ge];
  cnts[Max[(1 + Total[Unitize@Subtract[Differences@#, 1]]) & /@ 
      Table[Sort[Take[perm, j]], {j, size}]]]++,
  {k, size!}];

dist = (cnts[#]) & /@ Range@bins/size!
mean = Tr[dist*Range@bins]
```

I'd suggest doing a run for some *k* less than *size!* to get some timings to extrapolate the total runtime before unleashing it for a complete run. You should be able to speed it further by

1. Parallelize parts where appropriate.
2. Take advantage of symmetry of results, cutting work by 1/2 and adjusting sums.
3. Short-circuit the finding of maximums.

I'd venture a runtime of a handful of hours if all three are done correctly.

Barring that, or you don't care about precision, just use your *RandomSample* based estimator - the rare events for size 12 will be the cases where the maximum is 1, these occur ~0.00043% of the time, so calculate sufficient samples to get a reasonable representation of those and you'll get an OK estimate.